# Date and Time in a name of manual backup SQLEXPRESS.

Tags: t-sql, sqlcmd

sql.sql

> `DECLARE @pathName NVARCHAR(512) 
>   SET @pathName = 'l:\Backup\db_backup_' + Convert(varchar(17), GETDATE(), 120) + '.bak' 
>   BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase TO  DISK = @pathName WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'db_backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10`

backup.bat

```
sqlcmd -S mycomp\SQLEXPRESS -U sa -P password -i sql.sql
```

Output backup format look like : **l:\Backup\db_backup_2014-05-22 17** ??
Why are not displayed Minutes,seconds and extensions ".bak" . I need to displayed date and time in a  format : YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS. Thanks for Answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not getting seconds because this statement:

```
Convert(varchar(17), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Stops the string at 17 characters, which isn't long enough to include all the data you want. Try

```
Convert(varchar(19), GETDATE(), 120)
```

Instead.

As for the fact that your filename is being truncated, this is probably because it contains a colon, which is illegal in file paths and names. Try this.

```
Replace(Convert(varchar(19), GETDATE(), 120), ':', '_')
```

Altogether, your SQL will need to be:

```
DECLARE @pathName NVARCHAR(512)

SET @pathName = 'l:\Backup\db_backup_' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), GETDATE(), 120), ':', '_') + '.bak'

BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase TO DISK = @pathName
WITH NOFORMAT
    ,NOINIT
    ,NAME = N'db_backup'
    ,SKIP
    ,NOREWIND
    ,NOUNLOAD
    ,STATS = 10
```

Comment: No problem. If it's a useful answer, please consider upvoting and accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

You are chopping off the seconds because varchar(17) isn't long enough to contain them.  Also, you can't have a colon in a filename.

Try this

```
DECLARE @pathName NVARCHAR(512) 
SET @pathName = 'l:\Backup\db_backup_' + 
    REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(19), GETDATE(), 120), ':','-') + '.bak' 
BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase TO DISK = @pathName 
WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT, NAME = N'db_backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, STATS = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Your convert is to short, You need varchar(19) and not varchar(17) and you need to replace : with -

```
   DECLARE @pathName NVARCHAR(512) 
  SET @pathName = 'l:\Backup\db_backup_' + SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(19), GETDATE(), 120), ':','-') + '.bak' 
  BACKUP DATABASE mydatabase TO  DISK = @pathName WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'db_backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
```